# dropwizard: read configuration from a non-file source

Tags: java, dropwizard

What's the right way to read configuration in dropwizard from something like a database, or a REST call? I have a use case where I cannot have a yml file with some values, and should retrieve settings/config at startup time from a preconfigured URL with REST calls.

Is it right to just invoke these REST calls in the get methods of the `ApplicationConfiguration` class?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Similar to my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29060357/846644), you implement the `ConfigurationSourceProvider` interface the way you wish to implement and configure your dropwizard application to use it on your Application class by:

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyConfiguration> bootstrap){
  bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new MyDatabaseConfigurationSourceProvider());
}
```

By default, the `InputStream` you return is read as YAML and mapped to the `Configuration` object. [The default implementation](https://github.com/dropwizard/dropwizard/blob/master/dropwizard-configuration/src/main/java/io/dropwizard/configuration/ConfigurationFactory.java)

You can override this via

```
bootstrap.setConfigurationFactoryFactory(new MyDatabaseConfigurationFactoryFactory<>());
```

Then you have your `FactoryFactory` :) that returns a `Factory` which reads the `InputStream` and returns your `Configuration`.

```
public T build(ConfigurationSourceProvider provider, String path {
  Decode.onWhateverFormatYouWish(provider.open(path));
}
```

Comment: Thanks! So it looks like I have to return an inputstream to a YAML file from this implementation. That is, read properties from DB, persist in a yaml, and then return a handle to it. Somewhat inconvenient, but should work I guess.

Comment: I didn't realize it was returning InputStream. It is somewhat inconvenient, I agree. As it looks like you can also configure how you handle the `InputStream` as well. It's still a little tedious since you still have to work with `InputStream` but at least you can work within memory. I will update my answer.

Answer (score 4):

elaborating a bit further on Nathan's reply, you might want to consider using the `UrlConfigurationSourceProvider` , which is also provided with dropwizard, and allows to retrieve the configuration from an URL.

Something like:

```
@Override
public void initialize(Bootstrap<MyRestApplicationConfiguration> bootstrap) {
    bootstrap.setConfigurationSourceProvider(new UrlConfigurationSourceProvider());
}
```

Comment: Thanks Daniele - wish I could accept both answers. Going with Natan's since my URL doesn't exactly return a YAML - I need to process it.